# eigenvalues are roots of unity proof of $\chi(g^{-1})=\overline{\chi(g)}$ for all $g \in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

$G$ is a finite group. Given a representation $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$, and lets its character be the map $\chi: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined my $\chi(g)=\operatorname{Tr} \rho(g)$.

I have to proof that 
$\chi(g^{-1})=\overline{\chi(g)}$ for all $g \in G$.

In my textbooks it says:

Since $G$ is finite, $g$ has finite order, so $\rho(g)$ has finite order, and its eigenvalues are roots of unity. If $\rho(g)$ has eigenvalue $\varphi$, then $\rho(g^{-1})$ has eigenvalue $\varphi^{-1} = \overline{\varphi}$. And the trace of $\rho(g^{-1})$ is the sum of its eigenvalues.

What does it mean if the eigenvalues are roots of unity?

Answer (score 4):

In a succinct presentation, the argument to answer your question would be as follows:

1. Let $G$ be a finite group (or even more generally a **torsion group**, i.e. a group in which every element is of finite order), and $\rho: G \to \mathrm{GL}_{\mathbb{C}}(V)$ be a representation where $V$ is a finite dimensional complex vector space. Then for arbitrary $t \in G$, as $t$ is a torsion element in $G$ we must have $\rho(t)$ a torsion element in $\mathrm{GL}_{\mathbb{C}}(V)$.
2. This means that $\rho(t)$ is **annihilated by a binomial of the form** $X^m-1$ (where $m$ is for instance the order of $t$), hence that **the minimal polynomial of $\rho(t)$ has only $m$-th roots of unity as its roots**. Since it is well-known that **the minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial have the same set of irreducible factors** (which in this case are all of degree $1$, since we are working over an algebraically closed field), **the characteristic polynomial of $\rho(t)$ has all its irreducible factors of the form $X- \omega$, where $\omega$ is an $m$-th root of unity**.
3. In general, it is well known that **if an endomorphism $\varphi$ of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over a commutative field $K$ has characteristic polynomial whose irreducible factors are all of degree $1$, then there exists an ordered basis $a$ of $V$ such that the representation matrix $A$ of $\varphi$ with respect to basis $a$ be upper triangular.** Clearly, the diagonal entries of $A$ will be none other than the eigenvalues of $\varphi$. Of course this will always be the case over an algebraically closed field.
4. If in particular $\varphi$ is invertible and thus has no eigenvalue equal to $0_K$, then the upper triangular matrix $A$ introduced above allows you to easily establish that if the characteristic polynomial of $\varphi$ is
   $$P_{\varphi}=\prod_{k=1}^n (X-\lambda_k)$$

where $n=\mathrm{dim}_K V$ then **the inverse automorphism will have characteristic polynomial given by**

$$P_{\varphi^{-1}}=\prod_{k=1}^n \left(X- \frac{1}{\lambda_k}\right)$$

since if $A_{kk}=\lambda_k$ then $A^{-1}_{kk}=\frac{1}{\lambda_k}$ (where by $M_{kl}$ I mean the entry at position $(k,l)$ in matrix $M$).

5. Returning to your original context and keeping the notations of 3) and 4) for the eigenvalues, if $\rho(t)$ has eigenvalues $\left(\lambda_k\right)_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n}$ then $\rho\left(t^{-1}\right)$ has eigenvalues $\left(\lambda_k^{-1}\right)_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n}$ and we have remarked in 2) that **all these eigenvalues are roots of unity and thus complex numbers lying on the unit circle** $\mathbb{U}=\{z \in \mathbb{C}|\ |z|=1\}$.

It is immediate that for $u \in \mathbb{U}$ one has $u \overline{u}=|u|^2=1$ to the effect that $\frac{1}{u}=\overline{u}$. Hence, the eigenvalues of $\rho(t^{-1})$ can actually be expressed as $\left(\overline{\lambda_k}\right)_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n}$ and from here it follows at once that
$$\chi\left(t^{-1}\right)=\mathrm{Tr}\left(\rho\left(t^{-1}\right)\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n \overline{\lambda_k}=\overline{\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k}=\overline{\mathrm{Tr}(\rho(t))}=\overline{\chi(t)}$$